# Android - What happens to background activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

Consider for example, I started a background process in one activity (let's say process to get user's location). Now, before waiting for it's response, I redirected user to another activity. So, I want to know that what will happen to that background process? Will it continue working even after redirection or it will be paused?

Comment: What do you mean by "background process"?

Comment: @DavidWasser I mean executing **doInBackground(Params... params)** of **AsyncTask**.

Comment: Please read the linked duplicate question and the very detailed answers. This should explain everything you need to know and more about the relationship between `Activity` and `AsyncTask`. The answers you've gotten are all wrong for `AsyncTask` and since you didn't indicate that you are using `AsyncTask` in your question, the people answering went down the wrong path to help you. Next time please be more specific about what you are using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: No. It will be paused once you start a new Activity. To achieve such a thing you should look into services

You can find all you need to know here:

Activities

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Services

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Answer (score 1):

If you process isn't in a `service` or an `Intent Service` then there is no guarantee that your process will complete. The process should be paused. The proper way to handle this would be to use an [Intent Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html). Setup an event bus to handle the response. I suggest using [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) as the event bus. Also here's an [Intent Service Tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-fundamentals-intentservice-basics--mobile-6183).